# Android Ringtone picker list with default option selected

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-alarms, ringtone

I am trying to display a window picker dialog in android with the default selection to be instead of "None" how it is currently, to be selected the default phone's alarm/ringtone.

Here is the code I tried:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,
                    RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION
                            | RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI,
                    RingtoneManager
                            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

See the screenshot for details.[image]

Comment: while using `ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER` it is showing list of apps to select ringtone from, so how can I restrict it to open default one directly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried this ? 
[Ringtone picker - radio button set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393016/ringtone-picker-radio-button-set)