# How to get Ringtone from system sounds

Tags: android, alarmmanager, ringtonemanager

I'm using `AlarmManager` to display alarms in my android app, I want to display a sound from the system available sounds as an alarm but the only availability for me is to choose between the already set sounds like ringtone, alarm, notification :

```
Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM); // OR TYPE_RINGTONE OR TYPE_NOTIFICATION
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, alert);
```

but I want to get all the system available tones and choose a one between them.

Comment: You can use Ringtone Picker
here is an example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393016/ringtone-picker-radio-button-set

Comment: @Ronish great, I never knew about RingtonePicker, that totally solved my problem, you can add a complete answer for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
Uri ringtone= RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(YourActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
```

And as stated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965102/1638739), you have to do the following:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, ringtone);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI, ringtone);
startActivityForResult(intent , 1);
```

And finally you get the selected tone "**uri**" which you can store in **`ringtone`** as shown below in onActivityResult()

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            ringtone = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
            break;    
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to always give the credit to the one that solved a similar problem before :) that's why I included the link into your answer