# Ringtone selection intent - default ringtone

Tags: android, android-intent, ringtonemanager

I want to let the user select a notification ringtone for the push notifications of my app. 
This is what I do:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
    intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    startActivity(intent);
```

This is the result:

[image]

So far so good. On some devices though, across all manufacturers, the 'default notification sound' (first entry in the selection dialog) points to the device's call ringtone, not the notification ringtone.

**When the user clicks on 'Default notification sound', the device's default call ringtone is played instead of the default notification sound**

The ringtones are set correctly in the devices settings, the `Intent` I fire seems to pick up the wrong ringtone.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: Try here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393016/ringtone-picker-radio-button-set

Comment: @RonTLV My problem is not to highlight the default ringtone. Tried to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by explicitly passing the `Uri` of the desired default ringtone:

```
    intent.putExtra(
            RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI,
            RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
```